# Bundle angularjs library written in typescript with webpack

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I have an angularjs module written in Typescript, it contains a collection of components. I need to bundle this library into one file that can be consumed by other angular apps.

Here's the output part of webpack.config.

```
 entry: './mylib.module.ts',
 output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'my-lib.js',
    library: 'mylib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
```

When I am including this "my-lib.js" in an other angularjs project, angular cannot find my module as if it's not loaded at all.

Here's how I need to use the module:

```
<script src="https://example.com/my-lib.js"></script>
<script>
   angular.module('myApp', ['myLib']);
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
</script>
```

Here are some the first few lines of the generated lib file:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory(require("angular"), require("angular-translate"), require("angular-translate-loader-static-files"));
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define(["angular", "angular-translate", "angular-translate-loader-static-files"], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["fnc"] = factory(require("angular"), require("angular-translate"), require("angular-translate-loader-static-files"));
    else
        root["fnc"] = factory(root["angular"], root["angular-translate"], root["angular-translate-loader-static-files"]);
})(this, function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_0__, __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_6__, __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_7__) {
return /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap........
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you share a little bit more of how you are importing the external module in your app? Also, could you share the first lines of your generated lib.js? Are you running webpack -p option?

Comment: @The.Bear I updated the answer. No, I am not using the -p flag.